# Let $T\in B(H_1, H_2)$. Suppose that Ker$T$ is finite-dimensional and that Im$T$ is closed in $H_2$. Ker$(T + K)$ is finite-dimensional for each $K$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert spaces, let $T\in B(H_1, H_2)$. Suppose that
$\operatorname{Ker} T$ is finite-dimensional and that $\operatorname{Im} T$ is closed in $H_2$. Prove that $\operatorname{Ker}(T + K)$ is finite-dimensional for each $K\in K (H_1, H_2)$.

1. Define Hilbert space as direct sum of two complemented subspaces
2. For compact operator use Hilbert Schmidt decomposition

Main idea is to prove that intersection of Spectrum of such $T and compact K is finite

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, typeset your mathematical formulas using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assumptions the operator $T : \ \ker T^\perp  \longrightarrow {\rm Im}T$ is invertible. Therefore for any $w\perp \ker T$ we have $$\|Tw\|\ge c\|w\|$$ for a constant $c>0.$

Assume by contradiction, that $\ker(T+K)$ is infinite dimensional. Then there exists an infinite orthonormal system $v_n$ in $\ker(T+K).$ As $K$ is compact, then $Kv_n\to 0.$ Thus $Tv_n\to 0.$ We have $$v_n= w_n+u_n, \quad w_n\in \ker T,\ u_n\perp \ker T$$ and  $$\|Tv_n\|=\|Tu_n\|\ge c\|u_n\|$$ hence $u_n\to 0.$ The sequence $w_n$ has an accumulation point, therefore the sequence $v_n$ has an accumulation point as well. This leads to a contradiction.